# SNS Batch Publish

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-device-messaging

I see AWS publish API for sending push notifications to devices.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html

According to:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/push-notifications-to-mobile-devices-using-amazon-sns/
We can
"Send messages directly to a specific device by calling the Publish function with the device’s ARN. You can easily scale this to handle millions of users by storing the endpoint ARNs in Amazon DynamoDB and using multi-threaded code on the server."

If I want to send push notifs to 100K users (who haven't registered to a specific topic), is there a multi-publish (or batch-publish) API, where I don't need to call the "Push notifications" API for every single user?

Comment: Did you ever get any information on this?  I know there is no batch publish, but I'm looking for pointers on how to multi thread to hit the best performance

Answer (score 1):

probably not. the devices need to be registered (i.e. for SNS you actually have to create the endpoint for each device).
After you have the endpoint you can subscribe them to either one or multiple SNS endpoint and start publishing notifications through them.